# How would I use regex to allow certain characters?

Tags: java, regex

Mainly I am using regex, and what my code does essentially, is sends a client return code if it does not contain the characters in regex. My problem is, I do not know how to allow spaces.
Currently this is my code, I would like to have allow a space, a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

```
if (username.length() < 1 || username.length() >= 13
    || !username.matches("[a-zA-Z_0-9]"))
{
    session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `[a-zA-Z_0-9][a-zA-Z_0-9 ]*` assuming you don't want a name to start with spaces.

Comment: As per your post "allow spaces"

Answer (score 2):

use the \w metasequence (words, letters, underscores), plus a space (or \s to match tabs too), in a character class:

```
var pattern = @"[\w ]{1,12}"; //c#, validates length also.
```

*edit*: this seems to work for single spacing only, does not validate the length though:

```
var pattern = @"^(\w+\s?)+$";
```

Comment: `\s` is a whitespace character and not only a space, it includes also some tab and line break characters.

Comment: the pattern should be ok, you may need to double backslash the backslash, though.

Comment: It seems as if it still allows double spacing in names, is there a way to stop that?

Comment: can't replicate the issue, it's breaking on double space for me..(using the closest to java i have, c#)

Comment: Hmm, Still seems to allow double spacing :s
If only I knew regex.. haha

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure you want to be Unicode compliant, so you should use

```
[\p{L}\p{Nd}][\p{L}\p{Nd} ]*
```

I created two character classes to ensure that it is not starting with a space, if this check is not needed, just remove the first class and change the quantifier of the second to a `+`.

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

> \p{Nd} or \p{Decimal_Digit_Number}: a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.
>
> \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language.

[More about Unicode in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
if (username.length() < 1 || username.length() >= 13
    || !username.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"))
    {
        session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
        return;
    }
```